# modal not hiding in ipad

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem with a modal that won't hide in an ipad device, but works perfectly fine in a pc browser. So I ask for your help.

php

```
    <div class="modal" id="modal_search">
      <form action="search.php" method="post" class="formSearch">
        <input type="text" name="search" class="inputSearch" placeholder="Search.....">
        <button type="submit" class="botonSearch"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

JS

```
var modalSearch = document.getElementById('modal_search');

var botonModalSearch = document.getElementById('btn-search');

botonModalSearch.addEventListener('click', showmodal);

window.addEventListener('click', clickclose);

function showmodal(){
    modal_search.style.display = 'block';
}

function clickclose(e){
   if (e.target == modalSearch ) {
   modalSearch.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

Comment: Try using your browser's device emulation, eg https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/. It may be a CSS issue that you're not seeing due to your screen dimensions

Comment: I don't think is css. if I change the 'click' with 'touchend' in clickclose then the modal work just fine in the ipad, but obviously stop working in the pc, ¿how can i use both click and touchend in clickclose?

Comment: Bind both events to the same handler perhaps

Comment: can you give an example?, I don't know how to do that, I'm a noob in JS.

Comment: Add both `botonModalSearch.addEventListener('click', showmodal);` and `botonModalSearch.addEventListener('touch', showmodal);`